# Postgres helm chart installation failed in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install PostgreSQL with helm chart dependencies in my Kubernetes cluster. But it failed in installation.

chart.yml

```
dependencies:
- name: postgresql
  version: "10.16.2"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

values.yml

```
global:
    postgresql:
      postgresqlDatabase: "postgres"
      postgresqlUsername: "postgres"
      postgresqlPassword: "password"

volumePermissions:
  enabled: true
```

[image]

In this method I was successfully Postgres installed in minikube

Comment: Nothing in a Kubernetes/PostgreSQL installation will ever produce a PNG file.  What's the actual error you're getting?  The two YAML fragments that you show here seem reasonable, but also just seems like a deployment issue.  Is there any application code relevant to this question, or is just just about deploying a database in Kubernetes?

Comment: please share commands you used to install `postgres` and errors you get. That will allow better to understand what you mean by `failed` and reproduce the issue

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean in last phrase `In this method I was successfully Postgres installed in minikube`? So it works on minikube but doesn't work somewhere else?

Comment: @moonkotte
I have successfully installed the application on minikube.  After that, I am tried to install my application in the Linode Kubernetes cluster.  This time Postgres installation failed.

Comment: @Amjedsaleel Thank you for response. I can think of missing a `storageclass`. Please check `kubectl get pvc` and `kubectl get storageclass` and update your question with this data. `minikube` uses some storage provisioner by default